# How to pass a value from Before Trigger to After Trigger

Tags: postgresql

I want to pass a value from before trigger to after trigger in postgresql, is that possible ?, I tried tg_argv, its taking values from a function, but its not exactly what I need,

What I am trying to accomplish is, I have an Audit table, where I have two columns old_rec, new_rec,
in the before update trigger I will populate audit table with old_rec of triggering table and return the primary key of audit table. now in the after update trigger I have to populate the new_rec for the same primary key of audit table, i.e I have to pass the primary key generated on audit_table from before trigger to after trigger,

Well I have the flexibility to change the design given an option (pgAUDIT, third party tools I am not interested)
Please suggest if there is a better way of doing this.

```
Before Trigger on ABC table
declare
l_id integer;
begin
  insert into audit_table (old_rec) values(old.*) returning id into l_id;
end


after trigger on ABC table
declare 
l_id integer;
begin
   l_id = (somehow get the value generated in before trigger);
   update audit_table set new_rec = new.* where id = l_id;
end
```

Comment: Unless you change the row in the trigger, the before trigger will see exactly the same data as the after trigger. There is no need to update anything in the after trigger

Comment: update abc table set name = 'stack overflow' -- changing from current value 'overlow stack', now inthe audit_table , old_rec will have overflow stack (and other columns), new_rec will have stack overflow (and other columns). here I am using the same row of Audit table to track both old and new rows of the ABC table

Comment: You have access to the old **and** new record in the before trigger.

Comment: l_id, that is mentioned in the before trigger is not a column of triggering table, its a variable which stores the value of primary key that is generated by inserting into audit table, I am not getting how old and new will have access to the l_id variable. can you please give an example.

Comment: You don't need the after trigger. You can insert the old **and** the new record in the same statement in the before trigger.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, it worked.

Comment: You are actually better off using only an  AFTER trigger to create audit. It still contains both the old and new data for that row. Postgres allows [multiple triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/trigger-definition.html) for the same event (ie multiple before row triggers) and "if more than one trigger is defined for the same event on the same relation, the triggers will be fired in alphabetical order by trigger name."  This means data could be changed after the audit record, but would  NOT contain those changes. An AFTER trigger cannot change the data. So all changes are captured.